# what number of azure subscriptiions is too many?

Tags: azure, best-practices, subscription, devops

My organisation has 50 azure subscriptions at the moment and is planning to grow to well over 500 for several reasons: each application will have its own subscription, techies have their own subscription, dev environments are created ad-hoc. There is a devops team and a finops team, both of which have scripting capbilities. But I'm wondering if anyone else has the same amount of subscription? And is it working for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Subscriptions per management group: Unlimited
> - Subscriptions per Azure Active Directory tenant: Unlimited

More information on that in this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits

Comment: thank you! have you seen 100s of subscriptions anywhere? is it common?

Comment: Does it matter whether it's common or not? This is what your company is doing. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I haven't personally seen how other companies manage their tenants and subscriptions. But you'd probably get different answers to this question. If you want to get opinions on your approach and ups or downs, you may better ask at the Microsoft Techcommunity. SF isn't the best place to ask subjective questions.